# 3 buckets and transfusions of integer quantities

Tags: combinatorics

We have 3 buckets, each of them containing an integer number of liters of some liquid.
Show that we are always able to empty one of the 3 buckets with a limited number of transfusions and with the following restriction: In each of the buckets, in each move we must transfuse equal number of liters that the bucket already contains.
Note that the buckets are large enough to be able to bear the maximum quantity of the liquid that we will use.

Comment: For example:  Let's assume we start with the following quantities: 5 10 11, then the successive moves are:
5 20 1,
4 20 2,
8 16 2,
6 16 4,
6 12 8,
12 12 2, and then the last move will be to move either of the 12 liters to the other bucket, but how can we generalise?